# what is backup and share in git

Tags: git, github

when I try `git remote -v` the following was shown.
I cofused what is backup and share ?
I couldn't understand what are they and why they are mixed.

```
% git remote -v
backup  ssh://git.test.com:2222/pkg/test/backup/user(fetch)
backup  ssh://git.test.com:2222/pkg/test/backup/user(push)
origin  ssh://git.test.com/pkg/mysite(fetch)
origin  ssh://git.test.com/pkg/mysite(push)
share   ssh://git.test.com:2222/pkg/test/share/user(fetch)
share   ssh://git.test.com:2222/pkg/test/share/user(push)
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: It's two remotes that you have added. There isn't any functional difference between those and origin, as far as git are concerned.

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Answer (score 0):

No "opinion" is needed.

You asked Git for a list of your remotes and that is the list. Git's answer is: You have three remotes and their names are `backup` `origin` and `share`.

The names have no significance: they are arbitrary. In fact: You yourself made up the names backup and share! (Don't you even remember doing that?)

Comment: If you cannot read the output of the question you asked Git, why did you ask Git that question?